# Change the Response Accept header content type if PDF is requested

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvvm, nancy

Let me explain my problem clearly. I am working on a project where a client can request a document over a HTTP request. We have a to check the HTTP accept header of the incoming request, if the

```
contentType = "application/json"
```

then it should return HTML content but if the

```
contentType = "application/pdf"
```

it should convert the html into pdf and return the pdf to the client. I got this working fine but I am having hard time to change the Response accept header contentType to application/pdf when the client requested a pdf document. I am very new to Nancy and this is giving me a hard time.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";`?

Answer (score 0):

Implement a custom response that inherits from Response :

https://gist.github.com/Sphiecoh/4863a4e29d8edd8da8f2329d6ab38000

Or implement the IResponseProcessor interface.